# Crypto Exchange that Offers Withdrawal to Banks in Saudi Arabia

Tags: exchanges, banks, withdrawal

I need any crypto exchange that offers withdrawal (cash) to banks in Saudi Arabia. There is one exchange that I know of is Fasset but it's still in its beta phase. I want to know if there's any other alternative to it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if there's any other alternative to it.

[Bisq](https://bisq.network/getting-started/)

If no offers exist. Create offers. Users run the client on their machine, create their offers, decide their peers, No KYC and you have the keys and everything is decentralized including disputes.

If any issues use the links mentioned in the bottom-right of the website:

[image: Community-Bisq]